# POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/addcontact 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: ajax, laravel, post, controller

Here I  present my code .I already included csrf meta on head of the view file. If you can please solve this problem or if there need to change provide suggestion.thanks.

Here goes the route..

```
Route::post('/addcontact','ContactController@addcontact');
```

Here the view file..

```
<div class="modal-body" >
            <form align = "left" id = "form-insert" method = "post" action = "{{url('/addcontact')}}"> 
            {{csrf_field()}}
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Phone</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Religion</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
                </div>
                <input id="signup-token" name="_token" type="hidden" value="{{csrf_token()}}">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
```

Here the script...

```
<script>
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });

    $("#form-insert").on('submit',function(e){

        e.preventDefault();
        var data = $(this).serialize();
        var url = $(this).attr('action');
        var post = $(this).attr('method');
        $.ajax({
            type : post,
            url : url,
            data : data,
            success:function(data){
                alert('success')
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

Here is the controller...

```
public function addcontact(Request $request){

            $contacts = Contact::create($request->all());

    }
```

Comment: Can you please add error message too..

Comment: Error on the title sir . Its the ajax error on browser console.

Comment: Can anyone provide a complete simple laravel-ajax code to insert data to db? If -then I will use that . Thanks..

Comment: Please add the screen short for the console eror

Comment: https://appdividend.com/2018/02/07/laravel-ajax-tutorial-example/

Comment: check your server's `error_log`. Works all the time.

Comment: BTW, you added the csrf token twice. `{{csrf_field}}` and `<input id="signup-token" name="_token" type="hidden" value="{{csrf_token()}}">` does the same thing.

Comment: Thanks all for consideration problem solved . I didn't provide name in input fields.